# Error of iterator in mys JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts

TITLLE
       
      
             
       
        [...]

```
<logic:iterate id="listClient" name="Client">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    [...]
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</logic:iterate>
```

But i have this error for my second iterate

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot
>   create iterator for this collection

Comment: does changing the 'name' or 'id' help? from Client to Client2 ?

Comment: Client is my list i try to change the id but i have the same error

Comment: In my Struts-Config client is define like this :
<form-property name="Client" type="com.[...].Client[]"/>

Comment: is that, both logic:iterate in same page or you using each logic:iterate in different JSP?

Comment: How about if you delete the second iteration completely? Are you able to iterate? I am asking this question because it doesn't make any sense to me when you are able to iterate once, but not again.

Comment: if i delete the second iterate is ok

Comment: Try  with adding an attribute <code>type="com.[...].Client"</code>

Comment: I think in order to help more, we need to see all of the code between the 2 iterations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Cannot create iterator for this collection` message is thrown by the iterate tag when it is not able to create an iterator for the collection you are passing to it.

The tag extracts an object from scope using the specified name, in this case `Client` and starts to check what type it is:

- array of objects or primitives;
- java.util.Collection;
- java.util.Iterator;
- java.util.Map;
- java.util.Enumeration.

If it finds one of this object types it extracts the iterator in the appropriate way. If none of the above are a match you get `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot create iterator for this collection`.

At this point I agree with Adeel Ansari's comment: "it doesn't make any sense to me when you are able to iterate once, but not again".

Are you doing something to the `Client` bean between the two iterator tags (i.e. is the presented code continuous in regards of the iterator tags)? Maybe you overwrite it with something that ain't a collection?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `id`, change the id of the second one

Comment: when i change the id for the second iterator i have the same error
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot create iterator for this collection

Answer (score 0):

use this type of iterater to solve this problem.............

```
<tr>
    <td><b>RECD from :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="vo.cuttingRecivedFrom" >
            <option value="">select</option>
            <logic:notEmpty name="storeList">
                <logic:iterate name="storeList" id="storeList1" indexId="count">
                    <option value="<bean:write name="storeList1" property="storeName"/>"><bean:write name="storeList1" property="storeName"/></option>
                </logic:iterate>
            </logic:notEmpty>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><b>RECD in :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="vo.cuttingRecivedFrom" >
            <option value="">select</option>
            <logic:notEmpty name="storeList">
                <logic:iterate name="storeList" id="storeList1" indexId="count1">
                    <option value="<bean:write name="storeList1" property="storeName"/>"><bean:write name="storeList1" property="storeName"/></option>
                </logic:iterate>
            </logic:notEmpty>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```